# How to make Selenium check link url

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a link that has a class of ".btn", sometimes the URL of that link contains either /apply/ or /apply/jump/.

How do I construct and if that returns true based on what I want to check?

E.g.:

```
if btn url contains /apply/jump/ 
print true
else
print false
```

I am using Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following block of code:

```
# Get all links with "btn" class name.
links = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a.btn")

# Go through the loop and check each link. Print result for each link.
for link in links:

    if "/apply/jump/" in link.get_attribute("href"):

       print("True.")

    else:

       print("False.")
```

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get the element ([this](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) is a great guide if you'd like to read more about this). Since CSS classes can appear multiple times on a page, this code sample assumes you just want to check the first match:

```
# This will get all elements that look like <a class="btn">
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a.btn")
if len(elements) > 0:
    element = elements[0]  # This gets the first matching element.
```

Then you can inspect the `href` attribute to see if it matches what you want:

```
return "/apply/jump/" in element.get_attribute("href")
```